# friend functions with const parameters

Tags: c++, reference, const-reference

I got to know that to make a friend function, friend function should be explicitly declared in enclosing scope or take an argument of its class. However, this one seems to be a caveat, I am failed to understand. Why does the call to `f1(99)` not works?

```
class X { 
  public:
    X(int i) {
      std::cout << "Ctor called" << std::endl;
    }
    friend int f1(X&);
    friend int f2(const X&);
    friend int f3(X);
};
int f1(X& a) {
  std::cout << "non-const called" << std::endl;
}
int f2(const X& a) {
  std::cout << "const called" << std::endl;
}
int f3(X a) {
  std::cout << "object called" << std::endl;
}   

int main() {
  f1(99);
  f2(99);
  f3(99);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `friend` or functions, it's just that an lvalue reference cannot bind to the temporary `X` required to call `f1`.

Comment: @Quentin, Right. I thought it that directin too. Then how come const could bind?

Comment: A function that is a `friend` of class `X` is also not required to accept an argument of type `X`.

Comment: @Peter It's not invalid, but in the case where the function is not explicitly redeclared at namespace scope you would never be able to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the functions with argument `99`; but all the functions expect an `X`. `99` could convert to `X` implicitly, but the converted `X` is a temporary object and can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const.

The temporary object could be bound to [lvalue-reference to const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Explanation) (and also rvalue-reference since C++11), then `f2(99);` works. And it could be copied to the parameter of `f3`, then `f3(99)` works too.

> The effects of reference initialization are:
>
> - Otherwise, if the reference is lvalue reference to a non-volatile const-qualified type `or rvalue reference (since C++11)`:
>
>   - Otherwise, object is implicitly converted to T. The reference is bound to the result of the conversion `(after materializing a temporary) (since C++17)`. If the object (or, if the conversion is
>       done by user-defined conversion, the result of the conversion
>       function) is of type T or derived from T, it must be equally or less
>       cv-qualified than T`, and, if the reference is an rvalue reference, must not be an lvalue (since C++11)`.